# how to access certain dotted value in helm ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3, configmap

i want to access dotted named value with helm to use in ConfigMap
the value is something like that

```
valuenum:
  joji.json: zok
```

i want to use it in ConfigMap with helm as this

```
{{ toYaml .Values.valuenum.joji.json }}
```

it returns syntax error.
could not find a fix for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself, when using index we can search for nested variables with quotes.

```
{{ index .Values.valuenum "joji.json" }}
```

[link for helm doc about index and more](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/)